# LINQ Select one field based on query from a different column

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to retrieve a field from my database based on the user.identity.name. I have tried the following but I can't seem to get a result for either UserName or CustomerId, but I do get "jmcgee" for User.Identity.Name. So dealerId ends up beging null, when I want it to return CustomerId (01d1).

What am I doing wrong? It looks like I have everything set up the same as other questions/examples here, msdn, etc.

**UserProfile Table**: UserName = jmcgee; CustomerId= 01d1

```
var dealerId = db.UserProfiles
               .Where(d=>d.UserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name))
               .Select (d=>d.CustomerId);
```

or

```
var dealerId = from d in db.UserProfiles
               where d.UserName == User.Identity.Name
               select d.CustomerId;
```

or

```
var dealerId = (from d in db.UserProfiles
                where d.UserName == User.Identity.Name
                select d.CustomerId).SingleOrDefault();
```

I've also tried FirstOrDefault to no avail, but that might be my lack of understanding how to set it up. I've even tried replacing User.Identity.Name with "jmcgee" just to see if that would work.

Here's more of the code (let me know if something else needed is missing and I'll add it):

**Controller**

```
TintagliaContext db = new TintagliaContext();

        public ActionResult OpenQuotes(string searchString, string excludeString, string modelFilter, int? page)
        {   // var dealerId = "01D1628";

            var dealerId = (from d in db.UserProfiles
                         where d.UserName == User.Identity.Name
                         select d.CustomerId).SingleOrDefault();

            string context = _customerRepository.GetContext(dealerId);

           Tintaglia.Models.Filter filter;

            if (context == "coverpools")
            {
                filter = new Tintaglia.Models.Filter { IsSubmitted = false, Order = quote => quote.Date_Created, SearchString = searchString, ExcludeString = excludeString };
            }
            else
            { filter = new Tintaglia.Models.Filter { IsSubmitted = false, DealerId = dealerId, Order = quote => quote.Date_Created, SearchString = searchString, ExcludeString = excludeString };
            }
            var quotes = _configurationRepository.GetQuotes(filter);
            var model = new List<ConfigurationViewModel>();

            foreach (var quote in quotes)
            {
                var viewModel = new ConfigurationViewModel();
                viewModel = viewModel.MapModelToViewModel(quote);

            model.Add(viewModel);

            }
            ViewData.Model = model.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 20); ;

            return View();
        }
```

**ICustomerRepository**

```
namespace Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.Repositories.Interfaces
{
    public interface ICustomerRepository
    {
        string GetContext(string dealerId);
        //bool Login(string userName, string password);
    }
}
```

**_customerRepository**

```
namespace Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.Repositories
{
    public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
    {
        //public string GetContext(string dealerId)
        public string GetContext(string dealerId)

        {
            using (var db = new TintagliaContext())
            {
                var customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.No_ == dealerId);
                return customer.Internal_Login == 1 ? "coverpools" : "default";
            }
        }
}
}
```

**TintagliaContext**

```
namespace Infotech.Coverpools.Portal.Tintaglia.CodeFirst.Models
{
    public partial class TintagliaContext : DbContext
    {
        static TintagliaContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<TintagliaContext>(null);
        }

        public TintagliaContext()
            : base("TintagliaContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        //New for Account Module
        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<webpages_UsersInRoles> webpages_UsersInRole { get; set; }
        // public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ConfigurationMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you're facing? You ask what you're doing wrong, but don't say how it isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: My dealerId is returning null. I want it to return the CustomerId (01d1).

Comment: it is probably returning null because it is null -- are you sure it is being populated correctly?  How are you populating it?  Please show that code.  There is nothing wrong with the code you provided.

Comment: Does the query return anything if you select all user profiles? db.UserProfiles.ToList(); Also you could try narrowing down the problem by selecting other column from the table or trying to query by different column.

Comment: @Hogan I've added more code, hopefully it's enough to tell you how it's being populated, I'm not sure. At least what I want it to do is connect to the database (through tintaglia context), which is working in other places and look for current UserName and return DealerId. Let me know if there's other code you want to see (tintaglia model, view, etc)?

Comment: @Kodetajs No it doesn't. That must be my problem. I must not be connecting to UserProfile correctly, I presume?

Comment: Any thoughts on why this won't connect to my table? I know it is connecting to the database in other controllers and as far as I can tell this one is using the same code. Here's the connection if that helps. `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TintagliaContext" connectionString="Data Source=SLD-GZQTHS1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=coverpools;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: I figured it out. I moved my context up in the controller. I'm not sure if this is what fixed it or if it was working and I was trying to use the wrong user. When I hover over var dealerId, it still says null (shouldn't this say what the variable is when I hover over it during debugging?), but when I hover over dealerId in the other locations, it shows the correct user. Thank you for your help @kodetajs, you got me on the right path.